# FMCW Transmit Signal and Fly-back Effect

Tags: radar, frequency-modulation, theory

I am studying a thesis about nonlinearities in the transmit signal and it mentions the following:

> The first 2,500 samples, which correspond to the Tmax of each of each
> sweep period and are affected by ‘fly-backs’ from the previous sweep,
> are set to zero, so that the number of processed samples is  =
> 10,000.

The thesis in question is "Estimation and compensation of frequency sweep nonlinearity in FMCW radar" by Kurt Peek.

Its the first time I listened about this Fly-Back effect and I searched about it and did not find anything usefull. Can someone explain what is it or send a reference so I can read about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scanning systems, an area is covered by slowly moving something (usually a voltage) from one value to another to do the scan in one direction. Then, a new scan must start at the same point, but slightly displaced from the previous scan. And it has to change back to the start very quickly.

That quick change from the end of one scan to the beginning of the next is called “fly back”.

Due to that quick change (high derivative), other parts of the circuit can be adversely affected.

It’s that adverse effect from the quick change that the thesis is trying to avoid.